# SpreadJS - get updated cell text on keyDown/keyUp event

Tags: javascript, jquery, spreadsheet, spreadjs

I am using SpreadJS version 12

What I want is to get cell text/value after each keyDown/keyUp event.

when I try to run `cell.text()` or `cell.getValue()` I get old value(The value which was present earlier when we focused the cell)

for ex.

If cell 0,0 has a text "Sample"

1. double click that cell to start editing
2. we press backspace 2 times.
3. in keyDown event we try to get cell text by cell.text()/cell.getValue()
4. Expected output is "Samp", but I am getting "Sample".

Comment: it might be referencing issue.

Comment: But how can I address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

we can bind following event.

```
  self.sheet.bind(GC.Spread.Sheets.Events.EditChange, function(e, args) {
      console.log(args.editingText);
  });
```